# CATransaction complete block success or failure

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, core-animation

I am working with Core Animation using `CATransaction`. I am using `setCompletionBlock` in order to capture when the animation is complete so that I can do stuff with the data in the view controller, but I want the animation to be interruptible. Eg. when I call

> [self.layer removeAllAnimations]

the animation should stop but the setCompletionBlock should also **KNOW** if the animation succeeded or failed.

With UIView animation, this is possible since there is a `finished` variable passed in the completion block and with CAAnimationGroup this is also possible with a `finished` variable passed to the delegate. How do I accomplish the same with a `CATransaction`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using key-value coding, you can pass any variable you like into the current transaction where it can be picked up by the completion block later. CATransaction, CAAnimation, CALayer, they all accept arbitrary key-value pairs which you can create and use to your heart's content.

[https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/graphicsimaging/Reference/CATransaction_class/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/CATransaction/setValue:forKey:](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/graphicsimaging/Reference/CATransaction_class/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/CATransaction/setValue%3aforKey%3a)

Comment: I've used the trick of attaching arbitrary key/value pairs to CAAnimation objects and CALayer objects and it works great. However, CATransaction is nothing but class methods. I don't know of a way to interact with an INSTANCE of CATransaction, and have no idea how you would attach a key/value pair to a class like CATransaction. Can you explain?

Comment: No instance is involved; you say `[CATransaction setValue:@YES forKey:@"cancelled"]` and pick it up later with `if ([CATransaction valueForKey:@"cancelled"])`. Did you even look at the link to docs that I provided?

Comment: Yea, it seems to be scoped for nested CATransactions. Just sucks how it's such a manual process and that you have to check to make sure every change for sublayers are also canceled. Although this is the answer, I decided against using it for the reason mentioned. UIView and CAAnimationGroup keeps track of it for you so I am sticking to those for now until I can no longer use them anymore.

Comment: I did read the docs, but apparently not closely enough. I thought I remembered a protocol declaration that was common to CALayer and CAAnimation that gave it the ability to add new key/value pairs. I managed to miss the bit at the end.