# How to tell if CATransaction complete block called when animation complete or removed

Tags: ios, swift, core-animation

I am building a timer and I want to get notified when my animation is complete, such that I can proceed with the logic.

I am trying to use CATransaction's complete block. But it gets called when either the animation completes or it is removed. Is there a way to tell the difference?

I am basically asking the same question as this one: [CATransaction complete block success or failure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23838747/catransaction-complete-block-success-or-failure)

In the answer it says use CATransation's setValue. But I have no idea how.

Comment: Using a CATransaction completion block is not wrong, but it is not common either. Other kinds of animation have completion blocks that tell you what happened (or are not called if the animation didn't complete). Perhaps it would be better if you showed what you are actually doing and _ask_ how to accomplish it, rather than _assuming_ a particular way of accomplishing it (also called an x-y question).

Comment: Thanks. I am using a timer implementation i found: https://github.com/andresinaka/SnapTimer . What I want to achieve is set a timer for a certain period time and do something when the timer finishes. The view showing the timer can be switched away so completion block can be called at that time as well. I didnt choose to use CATransaction, but snaptimer uses it. If anyone can show me how to do this without it I am happy to follow.

Comment: Cool but I don’t understand the problem. The class gives you completion function callbacks for the animations. Why not use them?

Comment: because that function gets called when 1. animation finishes or 2. animation removed. But i only want to react upon the first case, yet there is no way i can see to do this. The link i posted in the main question was asking the same thing, and the answer seemed to be setValue of CATransaction. I just don't know how.

Comment: What I'm getting at is: if you know a definite circumstance where the completion function will be called and its functionality should not be executed ("The view showing the timer can be switched away"), why can't the completion function look around and see whether that circumstance is the case and, if so, do nothing?